# Searching an ArrayList of objects by one of the object's attributes

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` in which objects are generated and stored in by this code:

```
btSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            members.add(new member (name, id, mail, ccard, address));
            Toast.makeText(MemReg_activity.this, "Member Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            etname.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Now I want to search this list by `name` from other activity
Is there a way to do this ?
If not, is there any other way other than using an `ArrayList` that will help me to do this?

Member class

```
package com.fawzyx.movie_rental_store;

public class Member extends Customer {

    String id;
    String mail;
    String ccard;
    String address;

    public Member (String name, String id, String mail, String ccard, String address) {
        this.name = name; 
        this.id = id;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.ccard = ccard;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;    
    }
}
```

Comment: i will take that in consideration in validation

Comment: what should happen if you find at least 2 entries with same name? Is the search still valid?

Comment: its supposed to be a list of movies
so i think yes there wont be a problem

Comment: @Fawzinov Please review my edit, to learn about Java formatting conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method for finding a `member` by `name` if `name` is unique:

```
public Member findMemberByName(String name) {
    // go through list of members and compare name with given name
    for(Member member : members) {
        if (member.getname().equals(name)) {
            return member; // return member when name found
        }
    }
    return null; // return null when no member with given name could be found
}
```

and if `name` is not unique the method returns an `ArrayList` containing all matches

```
public ArrayList<Member> findMemberByName(String name) {
    ArrayList<Member> matches = new ArrayList<Member>();
    // go through list of members and compare name with given name
    for(Member member : members) {
        if (member.getname().equals(name)) {
            matches.add(member); // adds matching member to the return list
        }
    }
    return matches; // return the matches, which is empty when no member with the given name was found
}
```

For doing this in another `Activity` you have to pass `members` to this other Activity. See [Starting another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: .name is a function in movies class which returns the name .. am i right ?

Comment: I don't know, you tell me, it's your code. Provide your member class in your question for a more exact answer.

Comment: @Fawzinov has said in previous comments that Name is not a unique property. Thus, this method would just return the first match of the Name value in what you call `members` and not all items with Name `name`

Comment: i meant you're supposing that

Comment: @Fawzinov yes, please add your member class in the question to correct my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching once, just loop. If you will make the list once and search many times, you may want to create a separate hash map with the name as the key and a list of objects as the value. Then you could simply look up the key to get every object that matches.